# Need help to append dataframe in for loop in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We have list of conditions that needs to be applied to query in the where clause

```
Conditions=[
  Condition-1
  Condition-2
  ...
  Condition-n
]
```

and we have query like

```py
for condition in Conditions:
    df = spark.sql("SELECT col1, col2 from table where" + condition)
```

But we want one final dataframe with result of all the conditions how to do that...our requirement is something like that..

Comment: so is that a long multiple `AND` condition?

Answer (score 0):

If your conditions are multiple `AND`s you could just join them.

Example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    data = [
        {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
        {"a": 3, "b": 3, "c": 7},
        {"a": 2, "b": 3, "c": 5},
    ]
    conditions = [
        "a > 2",
        "b < 4",
        "c > 5",
    ]
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
    df = spark.sql("SELECT a, b from table where {}".format(" AND ".join(conditions)))
    df.show()
```

Result:

```
+---+---+                                                                       
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  3|  3|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Hi,Thank for the quick response. but we have lot of checks and based on that we append conditions. so the requirement is same as about

Comment: @user2260543 Not sure if I understand. So for each condition you are creating a separate DF and then you want to have a large one where all the separate DFs are together?